# How to retrieve Domain Name from Site URL

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having the Site URL like::

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

and I want to just find the Domain name of the Site ::
So that Answer should be like::

```
stackoverflow.com
```

How can It be done?

Is there any option of doing it in Jquery / C# ??
the Above given site is not the Fixed value.

Comment: `((?!(.*/)).)*` use this regex in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `System.Uri` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

```
new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com").Host
```

Answer (score 1):

For pure JavaScript, see [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.location) from MDN.

If the page url is "http://www.example.com:8080",

Than you may access its hostname through:

```
window.location.hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com/").Host);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way using javascript :

```
var url = window.location

var domain = url.replace("http://","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class and you can use [`.Host`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) property like;

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
Console.WriteLine(u.Host);
```

If it is string;

```
string s = "http://stackoverflow.com";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"/") + 1));
```

Both prints

```
stackoverflow.com
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/32pp1u).